# TypeScript копирование массива

Tags: javascript, typescript

Столкнулся с интересным (для меня) примером:

```
  archive(): void {
    var oldTodos = this.todos;
    console.log(this.todos);
    console.log(oldTodos);
    this.todos = [];
    console.log(oldTodos);
    console.log(this.todos);
    oldTodos.forEach((todo: Todo) => {
      if (!todo.done) this.todos.push(todo);
    });
  }
```

Масив ведь имеет ссылочный тип, верно? И вроде бы, `this.todos = [];` должен просто перетереть массив и по всем ссылкам теперь будет пустой массив, но это не так и он ведет себя не как ссылочный тип. В чем тут дело и где я ошибаюсь?
Весь код: http://plnkr.co/edit/x0aeMXEwYo67pAWYXzfA?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понял вопрос:

1. была ссылка на массив: `this.todos`
2. сохранили эту ссылку в переменную  `var oldTodos = this.todos;`
   теперь на один массив две ссылки: `this.todos` и `oldTodos`
3. присвоили `this.todos` ссылку на новый массив `this.todos = [];`
   теперь `this.todos` ссылается на `[]`, а `oldTodos` продолжает ссылаться на старый массив
4. бежим по старому массиву и копируем ссылки на его элементы в новый.

Массив тут вполне себе ведет себя как ссылочный тип.

Возможно, если бы использовался метод `filter` было бы понятнее

```
archive(): void {
    this.todos = this.todos.filter((todo: Todo)=> !todo.done);
}
```